# Regex - select whitespaces excluding whitespaces after prepositions

Tags: regex

I need regular expression to select whitespaces excluding whitespaces after prepositions (or short words, 1-3 char).

Example:
Namesti I. P. Pavlova

only selected whitespace will be after word "Namesti".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want the space to follow a minimum of 4 letters we can use

```
((?<=[a-zA-Z]{4})\s)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/Tlp2xS/1

If numbers are also accepted

```
((?<=[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})\s)
```

Or the shorter pattern

```
((?<=\w{4})\s)
```

Test to see what suits your needs because you have only given one sample string so there may be edge cases you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookback.
I have only put a point in the look back. You could add comma, colon, semi-colon etc. if needed.

```
((?<![.])\s)
```

see https://regex101.com/r/7MLjkh/1

Comment: Thank you! That matches the example. But this excludes only whitespaces after dot. 
I need 1-3 char instead of dot. I tried something like this: ((?<![[a-zA-Z]{1-3}])\s), but does not worked :(